# Rudin RCA (Real and Complex Analysis) Theorem 5.4 (If a linear transformation is continuous then it is bounded)

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-analysis, banach-spaces

In the proof of Theorem 5.4 in Rudin RCA (Real and Complex Analysis), the following conclusion is reached.

> Specifically regarding the portion that (c) implies (a). That is if
> $\Lambda$ is continuous at one point of $X$ then $\Lambda$ is bounded.

I am not sure how the above was arrived at. Attached below is the full theorem and proof of Theorem 5.4 - with all the relevant symbols and terminology - from Rudin RCA.

[image]
[image]

My attempt is given below to complete the last step in the proof from Rudin.

$$
\left\Vert \Lambda x\right\Vert <\epsilon
$$
$$
\Rightarrow\frac{\left\Vert \Lambda x\right\Vert }{\delta}<\frac{\epsilon}{\delta}
$$
$$
\Rightarrow\left\Vert \Lambda\frac{x}{\delta}\right\Vert <\frac{\epsilon}{\delta}
$$
$$
\Rightarrow\sup\left\Vert \Lambda\frac{x}{\delta}\right\Vert \leq\frac{\epsilon}{\delta}
$$
$$
\Rightarrow\left\Vert \Lambda\right\Vert \leq\frac{\epsilon}{\delta}
$$

```
Can you please clarify if there are mistakes in the above?
Can you also suggest alternative ways of deriving the above result?
```

In the last step above, we have used the definition of $\Lambda$ (Definition 5.3) which is given below. Here we are not using the condition that $\left\Vert{x}\right\Vert < \delta$ which would also imply that $\left\Vert\frac{x}{\delta}\right\Vert<1$ and not $\left\Vert\frac{x}{\delta}\right\Vert\leq1$ as needed by Definition 5.3

[image]

Also Definition 5.3 shows that $\Lambda$ is the smallest number such that the following inequality holds for every $x\in X$. Perhaps we can use this instead.

$$
\left\Vert \Lambda x\right\Vert \leq\left\Vert \Lambda\right\Vert \left\Vert x\right\Vert 
$$

Reference: [Rudin's RCA $5.3$ Definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4657660/rudins-rca-5-3-definition)

Please let me know if any additional clarifications are needed. I could be overlooking something simple and hence happy to delete this question if that is the case.

Comment: Sorry to say that none of your steps make sense.  What are $\epsilon$ and $\delta$? Where did you use the hypothesis of part c)?

Comment: @geetha290krm Please see the images with the proof for Theorem 5.4. $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ are defined there. They come from the standard symbols used in the definition of continuity. I have given Theorem 5.4 at the bottom, I will move it up so it can be seen more easily - and earlier.

Comment: For what $x$ and what $\epsilon$ do you have the first inequlaity $\|\Lambda x\|<\epsilon$?

Comment: @geetha290krm Yes, please see the last but one line of the proof of Theorem 5.4 from Rudin in the picture.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez The practise that I use - and so should everyone else including you so that it becomes easier for someone not familiar with the material - is that the first time an abbreviation appears it should be given in full. The next time just the abbreviation can be given. The title should always give full form and abbreviations if necessary ...

Comment: It appears that are trying to find out how to finish the proof that Rudin gave. That point is not clear from the way you wrote the question.

Comment: @geetha290krm I have added additional clarifications regarding this.

Comment: You have to start with an **arbitrary** $x$. That is important. You started with an $x$ such that $\|x\|<\delta$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Please look at the proof from Rudin ... It clarifies how we get the condition $\left\Vert x\right\Vert <\delta$ What I am doing is simply trying to complete the conclusions that come after this.